# C++ Huffman Tree and Pointers

Tags: c++

I am creating a Huffman Tree and to do so I started with making a Min Heap.  The heap is set up and works sorting the values by frequency in the document but my problem comes when I try to start creating the tree.

I am popping the top two items off the heap and putting a node above them and reinserting into the heap.  The heap is array based so it does not touch the *left and *right pointers of the nodes.  When the heap is down to only one node however both it's left and right node pointers are null so I believe it may be an issue with my pointers...? I am new to c++ from java for give my dumb mistakes.

```
 while(theHeap.getheapSize() > 1)
    {
        Node top;
        Node *min1=new Node(theHeap.topandPop());
        Node *min2=new Node(theHeap.topandPop());
        top.left=min1;
        top.right=min2;
        top.freq=min1->freq+min2->freq;
        theHeap.insert(top);
    }
    Node r=theHeap.topAndPop(); //null pointers for left and right children

--------------------------------------
    //code for heap.  arr is in the header file is Node *arr;

void Heap::insert(Node c)
{
    if (heapSize != arrSize)
    {
        heapSize=heapSize+1;
        arr[heapSize - 1] = c; //does this call copy constructor???
        percolateUp(heapSize - 1);
    }
}
void Heap::percolateUp(int nodeIndex) {

    int parentIndex;
    Node tmp;
    if (nodeIndex != 0)
    {
        parentIndex = getParentPos(nodeIndex);
        if (arr[parentIndex].freq > arr[nodeIndex].freq)
        {
            tmp = arr[parentIndex];
            arr[parentIndex] = arr[nodeIndex];
            arr[nodeIndex] = tmp;
            percolateUp(parentIndex);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `std::priority_queue` for the heap?

Comment: It's a homework assignment and we are not allowed to use standard library.

Comment: Just to make sure: `top` goes out of scope, so hopefully `insert()` calls a copy constructor instead of just taking an address?

Comment: I wrote the copy constructor for node. In the heap class I have an array of nodes and the assignment is done by arr[heapSize - 1] = c; where c is the node I passed as the parameter.

Comment: @Westin: Could you provide the code of theHeap?

Comment: I just added the code by editing my initial question.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code for the copy ctor of Node as well as Heap::topandPop()?

Answer (score 3):

First I would recommend not mixing instances and pointers, your task will be much simpler if you choose one. In this case I think it would be appropriate to store a pointer to a Node in the heap, rather than an instance, the added benefit is that pointers behave more like you are accustomed to from Java, no need to worry about copy construction and assignment. You only need to remember to delete them (unlike in Java), something that can be done in the dtor of Heap.

Secondly, to answer the question in your code comment: No the copy ctor is not invoked in Heap::insert(), rather the assignment operator is invoked. Whether that is a problem or not depends on what your Node class looks like.